# SQL select distinct column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I've a query which returns the following data

[image]

as you can see in the image the colored groups are similar regarding column "A"
i want to take the first occurrence of these rows regarding column "A" and discard the rest.

so i can end up with this result.

[image]

any solutions?

Thanks :)

**Update:**

this is the original query results
[image]

Comment: what was the sort criteria used to generate that first table?

Comment: Are there any unique & sorted columns available on the table not shown in this view?

Comment: Post if possible the data in a text format, to be able to use it on a query. That will save time to answerers and, usually, better and quicker asnwers.

Comment: actually these groups were scattered but i grouped them using Excel, but i can still get similar result using Order by A.

Comment: i've updated the post with the original query result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it as follows:

```
WITH T(A, B, C, D, RowNum) AS 
(
    SELECT A, B, C, D, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY A)
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT * FROM T
WHERE 
    RowNum = 1
```